# How to determine whether an image is optimized?

Tags: php, image, optimization

Ive got a strange task. Specifically i want to check for insane media file sizes for now. If possible, it would be nice if i could take image dimensions into consideration as well. For example, it's acceptable if a large image takes up 80kb, but not for a 20x20 px image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off @BoltClock's comment, you would need to define what makes an image optimized vs non-optimized.

Something like a definition table to go off of in your validation:

- Maximum image size = 1MB X 2000px x 2000px
- Relative Ratio of size to dimensions of file

The above could be checked easily (without GD for instance) using something like the [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function.

Comment: Thx guys. What i will do is get original image, make some optimizations, compare, look for result.